# how can you install a tool in master jenkins and use it on the salve

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

How can you install a tool in master jenkins and use it on the salve

So what I am trying to do is, say I install a tool on my Master, (ex NodeJs, or what ever) and

Now is there a way to have the Salve (auto install the tool on it self from master, or use the master server tool) without me having to install the tool on the slave.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use the "Launch slave via execution of command on the Master" method to start your slave, and in that master command call a script that copies a master tool directory tree to the slave using rsync or similar.  See the [Jenkins Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-WriteyourownscripttolaunchJenkinsslaves) for more details.